# Convert hex codes into ASCII characters within a URL using Mac Terminal

Tags: url, terminal, hex, ascii

I have a text file with many URLs, however, some of them contains hexadecimal codes like `%5D`, `%28`, `%3D` etc. I would like to use a terminal command to convert these hex codes into ASCII characters.
For example, I want this:
`https://51.15.54.108/%3Fdir%3DCloud`

to become this:

`https://51.15.54.108/?dir=Cloud`

I guess, there must be a way how to accomplish this using `sed`, `awk`, `ex` or perhaps `iconv`. I am also open to using python as well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` functions:

**BASH**

```
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

```
urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string>

    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}
```

Note that above `urldecode()` assumes the data contains no backslash.

Create a script with the function(s) and load your file:

```
#!/bin/bash

urldecode() {
    # urldecode <string>

    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b\n' "${url_encoded//%/\\x}"
}

input="/Users/<name>/urls.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  urldecode $line >> decoded.txt
done < "$input"
```

or command line

```
VAR="https://51.15.54.108/%3Fdir%3DCloud" ; printf -v VAR "%b" "${VAR//\%/\x}" ; echo $VAR
```

**UPDATE:**
Test script

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/Users/<name>/urls.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo $line
done < "$input"
```

This should output every line from your URLs file

Comment: thanks but I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with these scripts. Should I paste them in my terminal? (I'm using ZSH). Where should I link the file containing my URLs?

Comment: It doesn't work, says `syntax error: unexpected end of file`. If I change bash to zsh it says `parse error near `\n'` upon running.

Comment: The command line works fine on my Macbook. Or do you have a problem with the script?

Comment: The command line works but how can I link my file thereinto? The script is not giving me any errors now  but neither any output.

Comment: Updated script. it's giving you output now. If you change `urldecode $line` to `urldecode $line >> output.txt`. it's saving the output

Comment: Now the script finishes (which it didn't before) but without no output. If I do the modification in order to save output into a file, no file is created.

Comment: I've tested the script and it works for me on my Macbook. Please copy-paste code from my answer (to avoid typo). I'm using `nano` to create the script. If you add the output file, there's no output in the terminal and the output file should be in the same directory as the script (unless otherwise specified)

Comment: I copied the script, used `nano` to create the file but it still is not working. Could you be please more specific as to what specific steps are need to take?

Comment: I've updated the script (`script.sh`) with path for file with URLs (change name !) and added output file `decoded.txt`. Script and URL-file are in the same folder.
run script `bash script.sh`. Check your URL-file for line feeds Windows vs. Unix (copy-paste using `nano`).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same thig as you but I'm getting no output file from the script. Could you please elaborate more on that or perhpas suggest an alterantive way? Thanks

Comment: Are you getting results in the terminal without `>> decoded.txt` ?

Comment: after running the test script I get NO output.

Comment: Ok. Somehow you're not able to read the file containing the URLs. Can you please share your code and check the path?!
Can you read the file using `cat urls.txt`?

Comment: `cat testscript`
`#!/bin/bash
input="/Users/Martin/Downloads/testcopy2.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo $line
done < "$input"%     `
Here is my script with the path to the file.

Comment: Is there a percentage sign after `"$input"` If so please remove

Comment: can you read the file using `cat /Users/Martin/Downloads/testcopy2.txt` ?
Try copy the file to the script folder and run again

Comment: no, there is no % sign, it was an error when copying. I copied the file in the script folder and ran but no output still. I tried it both with absolute and relative paths

Comment: Then I really have no idea. The problem is that for some reason the script cannot read the file and therefore nothing happens. Try creating a new file with `nano` and pasting one line with a url in it.